# How can i print all values from a dictionary in a GUI in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application to enter a spreadsheet, check customers who have not paid the fee, list them in a dictionary and then print them out in a graphical interface made in Tkinter. The code itself works, my problem here is that it only prints the last value of the dictionary in the graphical interface.

Here is the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

root = Tk()

def func():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Output")
    newWindow.geometry("400x500+375+50")

    # Opens the spreadsheet and obtains the status of the last payment.

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']

    lastCol = sheet.max_column
    # latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

    # Checks the payment status of each customer.

    unpaidMembers = {}
    for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
            payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if payment != 'ok':
                cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
                email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
                mes = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
                unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
                print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Client:', client, 'Email:', email, 'Month:', month)


    #--- LABELS ---#
    l_label1 = Label(newWindow, text="Client", font='-weight bold')
    l_label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    l_label2 = Label(newWindow, text="Competence", font='-weight bold')
    l_label2.grid(row=1, column=2)

    v_result1 = StringVar()
    l_cliente = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result1)
    l_cliente.grid(row=2, column=1)
    v_result2 = StringVar()
    l_mes = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result2)
    l_mes.grid(row=2, column=2)


    # --- VARIABLES --- #
    result1 = client
    result2 = month

    #--- OUTPUT ---#
    v_result1.set(result1)
    v_result2.set(result2)




bt = Button(root, text='Check', command=func)
bt.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Spreadsheet template i'm using: https://prnt.sc/123qzfv

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to track ALL the clients and months (which I assume are the same as `cliente` and `mes`), then you have to tracek them all. Something like this:

```
...
    # Checks the payment status of each customer.

    unpaidMembers = {}
    clients = []
    months = []
    for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
            payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if payment != 'ok':
                cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
                email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
                mes = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
                clients.append( cliente )
                months.append( mes )
                unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
                print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Client:', client, 'Email:', email, 'Month:', month)


    #--- LABELS ---#
    l_label1 = Label(newWindow, text="Client", font='-weight bold')
    l_label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    l_label2 = Label(newWindow, text="Competence", font='-weight bold')
    l_label2.grid(row=1, column=2)

    v_result1 = StringVar()
    l_cliente = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result1)
    l_cliente.grid(row=2, column=1)
    v_result2 = StringVar()
    l_mes = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result2)
    l_mes.grid(row=2, column=2)

    #--- OUTPUT ---#
    v_result1.set('\n'.join(clients))
    v_result2.set('\n'.join(months))
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so much, I managed to understand and it worked perfectly.